# How to redirect to a certain screen when opening a dynamic link?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm developing an app that can receive Firebase's Dynamic Link. What I want is when a user click a Dynamic Link, the app redirects it to a certain `UIViewController`. So I have a code that looks like this on my `AppDelegate.swift` file:

```
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
        //return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url)
        return application(app, open: url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String, annotation: "")
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
        // On progress
        if let dynamicLink = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().dynamicLink(fromCustomSchemeURL: url) {
            print("open url = open dynamic link activity")
            print("url = \(dynamicLink)")
            let destinationVC = UIStoryboard(name: "DynamicLink", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DynamicLinkView") as? DynamicLinkVC
            self.window?.rootViewController?.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationVC!, animated: true)
        } else {
            print("open url = none")
        }
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url)
    }

func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
        // On progress
        let handled = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink(userActivity.webpageURL!) { (dynamiclink, error) in
            print("dynamic link = \(dynamiclink)")
        }

        if handled {
            let destinationVC = UIStoryboard(name: "DynamicLink", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DynamicLinkView") as? DynamicLinkVC
            self.window?.rootViewController?.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationVC!, animated: true)
        }

        return handled
    }
```

So what happened when I click the link the app opens up immediately but it doesn't redirects to the desired `UIViewController` that I wanted (in this case `destinationVC`). It directly went to the login page as usual. But in the debug area, the link appears like this =

> dynamic link = Optional(https://xxxx], match type: unique, minimumAppVersion: N/A, match message: (null)>)

Unfortunately I couldn't record the log messages when the app is not built by Xcode.

I'm very confused by this, what's wrong with my code? I'm new to iOS development so I'm not sure where did I do wrong. If you need more information feel free to ask and I will provide it to you. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your rest-of-code is working fine, and you are just facing issue while navigating to another view controller, then this solution will work for you.

If you want to open particular **ViewController**, while clicking on dynamic link, then update your code written within `restorationHandler`, below updated code will help you to redirect/navigate to particular View Controller

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
        // On progress
        let handled = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink(userActivity.webpageURL!) { (dynamiclink, error) in
            print("dynamic link = \(dynamiclink)")
        }

    if handled {

             let mainStoryboardIpad : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "DynamicLink", bundle: nil)
             if let initialViewController : UIViewController = (mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DynamicLinkView") as? DynamicLinkVC) {
                    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
                    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
                    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
               }

        return handled
    }
```

Hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: Hope this answer help you. Happy Coding :-)