# Why does pushViewController doesn't work after navigating through Dynamic Link?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm building an app that can receive Firebase's Dynamic Link and redirects it into a certain `UIViewController` after clicking the link. So based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62143951/how-to-redirect-to-a-certain-screen-when-opening-a-dynamic-link) that I asked, I have the code in `AppDelegate.swift` that navigates the app to the `UIViewController` like this:

```
func goToDynamicLinkVC() { // This function is in AppDelegate.swift
        let destinationStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "DynamicLink", bundle: nil)
        let destinationVC = destinationStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DynamicLinkView") as? DynamicLinkVC
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        self.window?.rootViewController = destinationVC
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

And in that `UIViewController` I also have a function that moves to another `UIViewController` if a user pressed a button like this:

```
func routeToDynamicForm() { // This function is in DynamicLinkVC class
        let destinationVC = UIStoryboard(name: "DynamicLink", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DynamicFormView") as! DynamicFormVC
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationVC, animated: true)
    }
```

But weirdly enough now that I pressed the button it doesn't move me to the next View Controller (in this case, `DynamicFormVC`). I've tried to debug the button whether it's working or not by doing this:

```
print("button tapped")
```

It shows the message on the debug area, but it still doesn't redirects to the next view controller. So what can I do to resolve this? If you need more information feel free to ask and I will provide it to you. Thank you.

Comment: Can `self.navigationController` be nil?

Comment: @ibrahimyilmaz what do you mean by this? is it something like this? `self.navigationController = nil`

Comment: No. If your viewController is not inside a navigationController this line never runs: `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationVC, animated: true)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the `goToDynamicLinkVC` function to something like this:

```
func goToDynamicLinkVC() { // This function is in AppDelegate.swift
        let destinationStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "DynamicLink", bundle: nil)
        let destinationVC = destinationStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DynamicLinkView")
        let navController = UINavigationController()
        navController.setViewControllers([destinationVC], animated: true)
        self.window?.rootViewController = navController
    }
```